# JButton background and foreground color swipe when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

Could any one help to implement below thing?

I have custom button which i have overloaded the paintComponent and plainText method to give my own look. the main focus of overridden is to give my own style for buttons.

so here the requirement is originally button background is white and foreground is black and when user press the button the color should revert like background as black and foreground as white.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing Swing components to modify how they «look and feel», you can provide your own **UI implementation** and attach it to a normal component instance.

Look at following methods:

- ['JComponent.setUI(ComponentUI ui)'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setUI%28javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI%29): method to set the UI strategy/decoration
- [ButtonUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html): the UI used for rendering buttons
- [BasicButtonUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html): basic implementation you can extend easily, overwrite    `paintButtonPressed` or the other `paint`-methods to create your own button look.